# Ext JS model proxy buildURL

Tags: javascript, rest, extjs, model, proxy

I am using REST proxies in my models. A model named community has a "hasMany" relationship to a model named Departments.

To retrieve the following records I simply call community.departments() which triggers the store load but with the wrong URL. The communityId parameter is not being included.

So I decided to build the URL I need, with the buildURL method. I need to pass the communityId property which is also the foreign key like this

```
/myapp/communities/{communityId}/Departments
```

but inside the `buildUrl` method there are no records beeing passes so again I cannot retrieve the communityId.

The relations are set correctly.

Plese help and advise I am really stuck here.

Comment: If you have a custom proxy, then you could add a variable for the community id, set that before calling buildUrl and then in the buildUrl function, use that communityId

Answer (score 1):

I can only support what Jaimie wrote (but still cannot comment ;-)). There's a nice article on Skirtle's Den about custom proxies and buildUrl:
http://skirtlesden.com/articles/custom-proxies

Comment: As it turns out there seems to be a bug in ExtJS 4.2 that parent key is not passed into buildUrl: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?272600-Ext.data.association.HasMany-with-rest-type-proxy-not-passing-owner-model-s-id&p=1089216